# Is my MacBook Pro's sleeping cycle normal?

Tags: macos, mac, sleep-wake, closed-clamshell

I'm currently using the aldente app and Belkin dock pro3, but I don't know what's wrong.

I need help

I'm currently using smb and sftp. So, I checked if there was an incoming signal with the tcpdump command, but there was no problem.

Below is the output of

```
pmset -g log | grep "Entering Sleep state"
```

in text and as a screenshot:

```
2022-10-23 01:10:29 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 923 secs
2022-10-23 02:26:31 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 196 secs
2022-10-23 02:30:47 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 940 secs
2022-10-23 02:47:13 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 6 secs
2022-10-23 03:47:48 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 934 secs
2022-10-23 04:04:07 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Sleep Service Back to Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 282 secs
2022-10-23 05:35:15 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Notification Wake Back to Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 8 secs
2022-10-23 05:36:08 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 911 secs
2022-10-23 05:52:04 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 6 secs
2022-10-23 05:52:55 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 960 secs
2022-10-23 06:10:41 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 927 secs
2022-10-23 07:26:33 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 234 secs
2022-10-23 07:31:27 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 942 secs
2022-10-23 07:47:54 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 922 secs
2022-10-23 09:03:57 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Sleep Service Back to Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 949 secs
2022-10-23 09:20:31 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 977 secs
2022-10-23 09:37:48 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Sleep Service Back to Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 1054 secs
2022-10-23 10:55:47 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 967 secs
2022-10-23 11:12:39 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 819 secs
2022-10-23 11:27:03 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 945 secs
2022-10-23 12:44:08 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Sleep Service Back to Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 947 secs
2022-10-23 13:00:40 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Sleep Service Back to Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 980 secs
2022-10-23 13:17:45 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 1045 secs
2022-10-23 14:35:25 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 959 secs
2022-10-23 14:52:09 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Sleep Service Back to Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 31 secs
2022-10-23 14:53:25 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 972 secs
2022-10-23 16:10:58 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Sleep Service Back to Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 266 secs
2022-10-23 16:16:09 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 650 secs
2022-10-23 16:27:44 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 332 secs
2022-10-23 21:12:49 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 6 secs
2022-10-23 21:13:40 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 7 secs
2022-10-23 21:14:32 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 198 secs
2022-10-23 21:18:35 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 322 secs
2022-10-23 21:24:42 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 644 secs
2022-10-23 21:42:03 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 104 secs
2022-10-23 21:44:33 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 39 secs
2022-10-23 21:45:58 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 20 secs
2022-10-23 21:47:03 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 13 secs
2022-10-23 21:48:01 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 156 secs
2022-10-23 21:51:22 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 205 secs
2022-10-23 21:55:32 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 634 secs
2022-10-23 22:18:44 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 904 secs
2022-10-23 22:34:48 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 543 secs
2022-10-23 22:44:36 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:63%) 59 secs
```

[image]

Comment: If possible, can you pls post the text version of the screenshot of the command output in your question in addition to the exact command and parameters you have used to get that output?

Comment: @Alper Thank you for your answer! 
$pmset -g log | grep "Entering Sleep state" I used this command